# Can't add products to cart - Magento store

Tags: magento, session, cookies, magento-1.7

A few hours ago everything just went fine on my store. Then for some reason I changed the settings for using SID in frontend to NO. After that I couldn't access the admin panel anymore. So I fixed that by setting the value for `web/session/use_frontend_sid` in `core_config_data` to 1. I cleared the cache manually by ftp and I was able to log into the admin panel.
Now the strange part. After all I can't add products to the cart. Everytime I try to add a product to my cart magento redirects me to the `enable-cookies` CMS page.

Comment: When I try to reproduce this problem at a different computer it doesn't show off. Maybe it's just a session or cache  related problem.
For now this problem seems solved. :)

Comment: Yep, clean your cookies (with webdeveloper extension on firefox for example) and it should be OK. Hope your website is not online cause your customers may have the same problem..)

Comment: @Bixi Now I'm back at my computer at work but magento always redirects me to `enable-cookies` page. I cleared browser cache, cookies and even the magento sessions. But nothing helped. This problem seems odd to me.

Comment: I tried Firefox, Chrome and even IE8 all of them are not working. Just Opera is operating correct. Strange...

Comment: Opera with turbo mode ? if yes : the problem is a network/DNS one.. try maybe to flush your dns: ipconfig /flushdns

Comment: No. But I solved the problem. See answer.btw thanks @Bixi ;)

Comment: ok good for you, but you just hide the problem by doing that (just saying ;))

Comment: It works. Nothing else matters for me at this time :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved the problem. I set the redirect when cookies are deactivated in the configuration panel to NO. Now it works like before.